# How to increase the speed of Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualization, haxm

My System Configurations are Core i3 CPU and RAM size is 4GB, Windows 7 Ultimate.

After  Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

**It stays there forever**

What can be done to increase the speed of Android emulator ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Check whether your processor supports [`Intel HAXM`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows). This will make the
  emulator run like a real device.
- Try [`GenyMotion`](https://www.genymotion.com/).
- Try [`BlueStacks`](http://www.bluestacks.com/).
- Alternatively, consider developing on Linux. The Linux kernel contains a module called [`kvm`](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) that is the equivalent of the Intel HAXM driver on Windows. The emulator is blazing fast on Linux with [supported processors](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Processor_support).

**References:**

**1.** [**Why is the Android emulator so slow?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator).

**2.** [**Speed up your Android Emulator!**](http://jolicode.com/blog/speed-up-your-android-emulator).

**3.** [**8 Tips to Speed Up Your Android ARM Emulator**](http://delphi.org/2013/11/8-tips-to-speed-up-your-android-arm-emulator-avd/).

**4.** [**How to speed up the Android Emulator by up to 400%**](http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't help it until and unless you have an high end laptop 
so what you can do is instead of using the built in emulator use **Genymotion** emulator, it's very fast compared to your inbuilt emulator
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Answer (score 0):

check that HXAM is upto date(version 6.0.1.0) and VT-X is enabled in our pc.
create a new emulator with ram size should be 1024mb.